# What is the meaning of `16 longs` and `110 words`, when reads the bits from a file

Tags: c, file-structure, binary, bit

I'm trying to read a `PUD` file format, that belong to the `warcraft 2` game map.
In the explanation of file structure, there is small phrases I don't understand it.

**What is this mean** (`16 longs`, `110 words`) **?**
Is this mean `16 longs` = `16 x 4Bytes = 64` or `16 x 32Bits = 512` or other.
Also the same thing with `110 words` = `110 x 2Bytes = 220` or `110 x 16Bits = 1760` or other.

**Here is an example**

> 16 longs -------> Units and buildings allowed. (16 players)

```
units bit order:
        0000000000000000000000000000000x        bit0:  footman/grunt
        000000000000000000000000000000x0        bit1:  peasant/peon
        00000000000000000000000000000x00        bit2:  ballista/catapult
        0000000000000000000000000000x000        bit3:  knight/ogre
        000000000000000000000000000x0000        bit4:  archer/axe thrower
        00000000000000000000000000x00000        bit5:  mage/death knights
        0000000000000000000000000x000000        bit6:  tanker
        000000000000000000000000x0000000        bit7:  destroyer
        00000000000000000000000x00000000        bit8:  transport
        0000000000000000000000x000000000        bit9:  battleship/juggernault
        000000000000000000000x0000000000        bit10: submarine/turtle
        00000000000000000000x00000000000        bit11: flying machine/balloon
        0000000000000000000x000000000000        bit12: gryphon/dragon
        000000000000000000x0000000000000        bit13: unused/unused
        00000000000000000x00000000000000        bit14: demo. squad/sapper
        0000000000000000x000000000000000        bit15: aviary/roost
        000000000000000x0000000000000000        bit16: farm
        00000000000000x00000000000000000        bit17: barracks
        0000000000000x000000000000000000        bit18: lumber mill
        000000000000x0000000000000000000        bit19: stables/mound
        00000000000x00000000000000000000        bit20: mage tower/temple
        0000000000x000000000000000000000        bit21: foundry
        000000000x0000000000000000000000        bit22: refinery
        00000000x00000000000000000000000        bit23: inventor/alchemist
        0000000x000000000000000000000000        bit24: church/altar storms
        000000x0000000000000000000000000        bit25: tower
        00000x00000000000000000000000000        bit26: town hall/great hall
        0000x000000000000000000000000000        bit27: keep/stronghold
        000x0000000000000000000000000000        bit28: castle/fortress
        00x00000000000000000000000000000        bit29: blacksmith
        0x000000000000000000000000000000        bit30: shipyard
        x0000000000000000000000000000000        bit31: unused
```